# Firebase simple login error "__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:"

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I'm trying to get simple login with email and password on iOS. I got the following error when logging in.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
>   objects[0]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x02eee1e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x02c6d8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x02eb4376 -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]
>   + 390     3   CoreFoundation                      0x02ee1c29 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 73    4   app                                 0x000ed30c ParseUserData + 428  5   app
>
>   0x0009e6e1 __37-[MenuViewController checkAuthStatus]_block_invoke +
>   161   6   app                                 0x0011f89f
>   __82-[FirebaseSimpleLogin attemptAuthWithToken:provider:userData:account:andCallback:]_block_invoke
>   + 461     7   app                                 0x00199df7 __43-[FRepo callOnComplete:withStatus:andData:]_block_invoke + 33    8
>
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x06e457b8
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15     9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x06e5a4d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14    10  libdispatch.dylib
>
>   0x06e48726 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340    11  CoreFoundation
>   0x02f5343e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 14    12
>   CoreFoundation                      0x02e945cb __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
>     13  CoreFoundation                      0x02e939d3
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467    14  CoreFoundation
>   0x02e937eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   15  GraphicsServices
>   0x03d535ee GSEventRunModal + 192  16  GraphicsServices
>   0x03d5342b GSEventRun + 104   17  UIKit
>   0x0192df9b UIApplicationMain + 1225   18  app
>   0x0010623d main + 141     19  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0708f701 start + 1  20  ???
>   0x00000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

My code:

```
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:FIREBASE];
FirebaseSimpleLogin *authClient = [[FirebaseSimpleLogin alloc] initWithRef:ref];

[authClient loginWithEmail:@"useremail" andPassword:@"userPassword"
       withCompletionBlock:^(NSError* error, FAUser* user) {

           if (error != nil) {
               NSLog(@"Success!");
               // There was an error logging in to this account

           } else {
               NSString *message = [error.userInfo valueForKey:@"NSLocalizedDescription"];
               if (message == nil) message = @"Please try again";
               [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showError:) withObject:message waitUntilDone:NO];
           }
       }];
```

Getting this error, my app don't get data form database anymore with crash.. Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the stack trace. The error is in your method ParseUserData, which you didn't show. In that method you are trying to create a dictionary, but the first of the objects that you pass in is nil.

In Xcode, set a breakpoint that triggers when exceptions are thrown, so the next time you can check in your running program what happens.

Comment: Yes, it seems auth error after login.This issue was my fault.Thanks for your answer!